# How do I use java Scanner class with complete file path?

Tags: java

How do I use it with the complete path? For example: "/home/user/file.txt"?

```
public class ScannerSample {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
  //Z means: "The end of the input but for the final terminator, if any"
     String output = new Scanner(new File("file.txt")).useDelimiter("\\Z").next();
     System.out.println("" + output);
 }
}
```

if I do this:

```
public class ScannerSample {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
  //Z means: "The end of the input but for the final terminator, if any"
     String output = new Scanner(new File("/home/user/file.txt")).useDelimiter("\\Z").next();
     System.out.println("" + output);
 }
}
```

it generates the error:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: \home\user\file.txt (The system cannot find the path specified)
java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
java.util.Scanner.<init>(Unknown Source)
util.CompareDevices.doPost(CompareDevices.java:54)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
```

Comment: Does the file exist? Are you on Windows? Why is the file path in the error separated by backslashes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand your question then you could use [`File(String, String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#File%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) constructor and the "user.home" property to construct that path like

```
new File(System.getProperty("user.home"), "file.txt")
```

or (on a DOS based system) if you really prefer

```
new File("c:/home/user/file.txt")
```

**Edit**

A more complete example, and using a [`try-with-resources` statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html)

```
File f = new File(System.getProperty("user.home"), "file.txt");
try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(f)) {
    scanner.useDelimiter("\\Z");
    String output = scanner.next();
    System.out.println(output);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Do you may have a complete example please? Because Eclipse is complaining here about convert Scanner to String.

I'm doing this: 

String content = new Scanner(new File(System.getProperty("user.home"), "file.txt"));

Comment: Edited to add a more complete example.

Comment: Hum... just figured out I'm using Java 1.6 due to limitation related to my server. Do you know maybe a solution that works in Java 1.6? This is generating the: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: util/CompareDevices : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0